# D3 Zoom's translateExtent not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I am trying to create a tile map with `d3 tile` and `d3 zoom`. I have set both the `zoom.extent` and `zoom.translateExtent` to `[[0,0], [width,height]]`. but when I zoom, the map jumps to the left top corner.

Here is the sample code

```
const tile = d3.tile()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .tileSize(512);

const zoom = d3.zoom()       
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]) //  issue in this line
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .scaleExtent([1 << 10, 1 << 15])
    .on("zoom", () => zoomed(d3.event.transform));

// applied zoom like this
svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
    .scale(-initialScale)
    .translate(...projection(initialCenter))
    .scale(-1));

function zoomed(transform) {
    projection
        .scale(transform.k / (2 * Math.PI))
        .translate([transform.x, transform.y]);
}
```

Here is the [complete demo in Observable](https://observablehq.com/@abdul-alim/zoomable-raster-vector-with-translate-limit)

Comment: Trying to unify zoom, projection, geographic, screen, and tile coordinates is enough to drive someone crazy. I'll take a look in a few days - on the road right now, home late next week, but the problem of clarity in units drove me to create an [alternative](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/3b1fb5ce8957dab2e3f5042931dddf6c) (which is certainly not finished, more of a demonstration of what could be possible - d3.tile is better now (early versions were a bit more cumbersome), but the units still leave a bit to be desired in terms of clarity)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid for your comment. In your d3-slippy you have a method `zoomTranslateConstrain` which i have passed to the d3 zoom. Will doing the same work in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key challenge here is understanding what you are constraining. The original scale of the projection is 1/(2π): world is projected to a space one pixel by one pixel (2π per pixel or 360 degrees per pixel). This allows for easier integration with d3-zoom, but is certainly not intuitive.

D3 zoom is used to modify the projection and has a scale value of along the lines of `1<<n`. This represents the width of the world after the zoom is applied. If the base projection uses a width of 1 pixel for the world, the zoom stretches it across `1<<n` pixels. 1<<10 being 1024 for example.

Now, the tricky part is that the zoom translate extent is applied at a zoom scale of 1. So, we need to apply the translate extent to the world as if it was shown within a 1x1 pixel box, even though, given a lower scale extent value of 1024 (1<<10), we never actually show the world as occupying one pixel.

So, our translate extent should be within a box bounded by the two corners: [-1,-1] and [1,1]. This helps explain the comment by Cornel. But can we do this programmatically? Yes.

*This is what drove me bonkers about this library: the zoom extent is not registered in something straightforward such as geographic coordinates, or screen coordinates, but zoom units relative to a 1x1 pixel world, introducing a new coordinate system to keep track of which could instead be tracked behind the scenes. This is certainly not intuitive and partially drove me to leave this module behind (explaining the link in my comment, d3-slippy is still pretty experimental, but should show what could be done - btw, the constrain method in the link would only work if you convert everything over to it).*

So, let's programmatically get the zoom translate extent of the screen as shown.

First, after we call the zoom and and apply the initial transform, the projection is updated to reflect the new zoom level and translate, so we can use projection.invert() to get the geographic coordinates of the top left and bottom right of the screen.

Second, we can (re)create a projection for our one pixel world and push the geographic coordinates of the top left and bottom right through it to get their projected coordinates within a one pixel world.

Third, we take the top left and bottom right projected coordinates within a 1 pixel world and we pass them to zoom.translateExtent:

```
   // Call zoom, same as before:
   svg
      .call(zoom)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
          .scale(-initialScale)
          .translate(...projection(initialCenter))
          .scale(-1));

  // Now we can work on setting the zoom translate extent:
  // Zooomed projected limits of screen in lat long:
  var top = projection.invert([0,0])[1];
  var left = projection.invert([0,0])[0];
  var bottom = projection.invert([width,height])[1];
  var right = projection.invert([width,height])[0];

  // original projection:
  var baseProjection = d3.geoMercator()
    .translate([0,0])
    .scale(1/Math.PI/2);

  // Projected limits of screen in projected unzoomed coordinates:
  var topLeft = baseProjection([left,top])
  var bottomRight = baseProjection([right,bottom])

  // Set the zoom translate extent:
  zoom.translateExtent([topLeft,bottomRight])
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Reid for your detailed answer. However it is still jumps to the bottom corner now. Can you apply the answer in my demo please?

Comment: I didnt see that, will look again, but won't be able until Thursday - I have 24 hours of driving over the next two dys... I had copied the code straight from the modified  obseevable, but will check it again.

Comment: @AbdulAlim, Able to look more now, however, I'm not seeing any issue: https://observablehq.com/d/a028605a652a6274

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Reid for your answer. Did you publish the observable example? I am unable to open it.

Comment: My bad: https://observablehq.com/@andrew-reid/zoomable-raster-vector-with-translate-limit (hadn't ever published anything on observable before)